# c++ can't access object pointer from 'this' in callback function

Tags: c++, pointers

I have some strange scenario 
I have object that pass to other object its 'this' pointer 
like this :

```
void GameLayer::startGame()
{

    m_pGameController = new GameController(this);

}
```

in the GameController constructor i set memeber with the GameLayer

```
GameController::GameController(GameLayer* gamelayer)
{
   m_gamelayer = gamelayer;
}
```

in the GameController i have functions that using callback functions 
like this :

```
GameController::methodA()
{
    CurrentGem->runAction(GameController::mycallbackMethod);
}
```

In the callback function I access GameController functions and members with 'this' 
for example:

```
GameController::mycallbackMethod()
{

int test = this->age();
std::string name = this->name();

}
```

But the problem is when I try to access the m_pGameController it gives me exception 
that says its NULL pointer

```
GameController::mycallbackMethod()
{

this->m_gamelayer->someGamelayerMethod();

}
```

The error is :

```
Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFF.
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: what is declaration of runAction?

Comment: What does the `CurrentGem->runAction` function look like?

Comment: It seems like you are doing a static method call to GameController::mycallbackMethod. This would mean all instance variables are not set and cannot be accessed, including this. What is the declaration of GameController::mycallbackMethod()?

Comment: the declaration is public none static function

Comment: That doesn't answer anything. Show the full function. Better, post an [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Any reason you accepted an answer which cannot possibly solve your problem? (if `mycallbackMethod` is made static it wouldn't be able to access members).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
CurrentGem->runAction(GameController::mycallbackMethod);
```

make the function `mycallbackMethod` static.

---

Side note:

To call a member function by pointer, you need two things:

- a **pointer to the object** (or object itself)
- and a pointer to the function

because pointer to member function doesn't hold reall address of the function but only offset inside object. A `static` member function however has no `this` pointer, it is the same as a regular global function, except it shares the name scope of class with other class members. So in this case you don't need pointer to object to call such callback.

Instead of having static methods and passing around a pointer to the class instance, you could use functionality of `std::function` and `std::bind`.

Comment: If this was true the code wouldn't compile. `runAction` might take a pointer to a member function.

Comment: but you are passing member function as if it was static function

Comment: No I'm not, this isn't even my code. C++ does have a concept of a pointer to a member function which you seem to be unaware of (why do you assume OP is passing anything as a static function?), so `runAction` might accept that. We'd need more information to know what the problem is, but since OP refuses to answer questions and accepted a nonsensical answer, I guess we'll never know.

Comment: @interjay runAction(GameController::mycallbackMethod) this call will work only if mycallbackMethod is static function

Comment: But `runAction(&GameController::mycallbackMethod)` will work for a non-static function. And some older compilers accept it without the `&` as well. But if this was the issue the code wouldn't compile, yet OP claims it does compile and gives a runtime error. P.S. Don't plagiarize code without attribution.

Comment: Sure it will work, if `runAction` is declared to take a pointer to a member function of `GameController`. If you still don't believe me, try googling for "pointer to member function".

Comment: I am referring to your assumption, made in first comment, above. also, please don't be rude/offensive as there is no need for such behavior

Comment: I did not make any assumptions, I only stated facts. And you still didn't specify what you think my "assumption" is. I consider it quite rude to just say "you are wrong" without giving any justification, which is why I responded as I did.

Answer (score 0):

When passing your callback function do call like

```
CurrentGem->runAction(&GameController::mycallbackMethod);
```

Where mycallbackMethod should be `static`.

Comment: Pointers to member functions are legal. Although there's a missing `&` here.